# Можно ли использовать ASP.Net Boilerplate в продакшене?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Всем привет.
На просторах интернета наткнулся на фреймворк [ASP.Net Boilerplate](http://aspnetboilerplate.com/) от [Volosoft](https://volosoft.com/). Судя по активности в [GitHub репозитории](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate) активно разрабатывается. Также на нём основана тема [ASP.Net Zero](https://aspnetzero.com/), которая разрабатывается этой-же командой разработчиков. Много в ней уже реализовано "из коробки", но не имея большого опыта разработки на ASP.Net Core не могу судить о том, насколько грамотно всё реализовано. Поэтому возникают некоторые вопросы...

Насколько качествен ASP.Net Boilerplate фреймворк? Использовал ли его кто-нибудь в "боевых" условиях? Не является ли он "сырым" или собранием "велосипедов с квадратными колёсами"? Является ли хорошей практикой использование каких-либо фреймворков для продакшена или это зависимость от сторонних разработчиков и их лицензий?

Answer (score 1):

Делал проект на ASP.Net Boilerplate и мое мнение что можно использовать в продакшене без проблем. Сделан качественно, хорошая документация, активная разработка и поддержка. Легко расширяем. Работает уже долгое время. Очень много функционала реализовано из коробки, который расширяется при необходимости. Из недостатков, наверное, достаточно сложная архитектура фреймворка и, как следствие, высокий порог входа. Не всегда всё интуитивно понятно. Нужно достаточно много прочитать мануалов и документации, чтобы разобраться в тонкостях и деталях.

Есть видео на русском, где разработчик рассказывает свой опыт работы с этим фреймворком. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ci1klCHQE6k

Comment: Как автор того самого доклада, подтверждаю, что фреймворк отлично работает в проде.

Answer (score 1):

Как человек работающий с этим чудом около двух лет черпнул немного костылей, которые были реализованы под капотом. Если совсем вкратце - мы дошли до паранойи, и любую фичу которая не работает проверяли на базовом темплейте, и очень часто они не работали и там, что было сначала удивительно, а потом закономерно. Документация приятная - пока не вдаешься в подробности.

Проблемы которые в большинстве случаев решает данный "фреймворк" - написание простых вещей еще более просто. Во что это выливается - отдельная история. Чего только стоит имплементация Repository с "асинхронностью" в виде Task.FromResult() и абсолютно идиотские нечитаемые extension'ы по типу var str = ""; str.IsNullOrEmpty().

Если вы готовы его постоянно реверс инжинирить ввиду весьма слабой документации - это ваш выбор.

На бумаге все отлично, и даже исходя из документации, пока как обычно не начинаешь с этим работать.

Начиная с авторизации\аутентификации, "выстрела" json ответа, логгинга - все плохо. Про мидлвары здесь не слышали, все сделано на своих костылях, и для переопределения ответа application service у вас вполне может уйти до 3-4 часов. Собственно такая же ситуация и по авторизации, переопределить\расширить AbpSession тот еще геморрой. Подсистема логгинга просаживает производительность

Лично мое имхо - если вам не нужна multi tenancy, и вы не дай Бог consumer продукт - **не используйте это**.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно согласен с мнением Антона Колесникова! Тоже использовал около 2 лет на нескольких проектах. Без изучения исходников никуда. Причем не только C#, но и Angular-шаблона.
Изучал детально Angular-шаблон. Сделал вывод, что он был портирован с какой-то старой версии и не в полной мере использует современный Angular. Основная проблема именно в документации - она недостаточна, если речь идет о деталях и более продвинутой разработке.